Flutter_Invalid constant value issue
I'm stuck with the Flutter UI project.
IDK, why invalid constant value shows up.
Asis :  backgroundColor: Colors.amber[800] 
If I change the code, it won't happen again.
 ToBe : Colors.blue
Is there any restriction using Colors Widget?
There is no "const CircleAvatar" in my code.

The hotfixes will add const where possible, but never remove it.  You should remove the closest const to the complaint area, and save the file, which will re-add const where possible.

the shade invocator of amber or "[]" implies it isn’t a constant value, which means  it is variable and not known during compile time. That’s  why Colors.blue is allowed and amber shade isn’t .  If you use the default of amber, like Colors.amber it would work.
I see CircleAvatar doesn’t have const keyword but maybe Row has, you can remove it if you like to use amber shades.
Or copy the code of the shade and create your own Color const value.

THX a lot!! it worked!
